# Adding langchain library via poetry add not working

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm on poetry `1.5.0`, python version `3.11`, trying to add langchain to my poetry project.
However, when running `poetry add langchain`, I'm getting the error

```
Using version ^0.0.174 for langchain

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

file could not be opened successfully:
- method gz: ReadError('not a gzip file')
- method bz2: ReadError('not a bzip2 file')
- method xz: ReadError('not an lzma file')
- method tar: ReadError('invalid header')
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```bash
poetry add --no-cache #{packet_what_you_need}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear pypi cache:

```
poetry cache clear pypi --all
```